# Jailbreak Tweak Learning - UIViewController (separate file) with initWithFrame - code provided

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos, cydia-substrate

I am learning how to create Jailbreak tweaks.

I hope this is just a simple question. I am using Theos.

I have the following setup:-

OneView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OneView : UIViewController

@end
```

=====================================

OneView.m

```
#import "OneView.h"

@interface OneView ()

@end

@implementation OneView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setOpaque:NO];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

=====================================

Tweak.xm

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include "OneView.h"
```

//This funciton works and compiles fine

```
%new
-(void)createView:() {
        UIView *view11 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 272)];  
        view11.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];  
        [self.view addSubview:view11];
}
%end
```

//This does not work it creates an error when I compile.

```
%new 
-(void)createOneView:() {
        OneView *view11 = [[OneView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 272)];  
        view11.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];  
        [self.view addSubview:view11];
}
%end
```

=====================================

Error

```
 Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
 Compiling Tweak.xm...
Tweak.xm:144:44: error: 

'OneView' may not respond to 'initWithFrame:' [-Werror]

        OneView *view11 = [[OneView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 
272)];  
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
Tweak.xm:145:16: error: property 'backgroundColor' not found on object of type 'OneView *'
        view11.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];  
               ^
Tweak.xm:146:31: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'UIView *' with an lvalue of type 'OneView *'
        [self.view addSubview:view11];

It does not like initWithFrame! is this something to do with headers !
```

Thanks

=========================

```
Error when inheriting UIView

bash-3.2# make package
Making all for tweak OneView...
 Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
 Compiling Tweak.xm...
 Linking tweak OneCall...
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OneCallView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Tweak.xm.249b7f24.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [obj/OneView.dylib.ba964c90.unsigned] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [OneView.all.tweak.variables] Error 2

=========================
```

Error when inheriting UIViewController (Updated)

```
        OneView *view11 = [[OneView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 272)];  
        view11.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];  
        [self.view addSubview:view11];
```

'OneView' may not respond to 'initWithFrame:' [-Werror]

```
        OneView *view11 = [[OneView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 
272)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made your OneView a subclass of UIViewController:

```
@interface OneView : UIViewController
```

But you have to make it a subclass of UIView:

```
@interface OneView : UIView
```

Comment: Hi, that's not the problem wether you inherit UIViewController or UiView it's the same error.

Comment: This is definitely the problem. UIViewController has no initializer function called initWithFrame:frame as shown in your error log. This function is used by UIView or any class inherited from it.  As your error log shows as well, a UIViewController has no property called backgroundColor. It's a property of UIView. I would suggest to check your code again

Comment: Hi, Sorry I didn't explain myself correctly in my previous comment so I apologize I was also color blinded and didn't see the background color property but its only there because I was cutting and pasting, however I am trying to get this to work with a UIViewController as well not just UIView.  I still get an error if OneView inherits UIView. I updated the error above at the bottom please take a look. Thanks for your help and be patient with me so I can get this :)

Comment: Hi Horse, I accepted your answer because I made a mistake in my question and the problem that I had was when I inherited UIView it was not linking correctly as you can see at the bottom above. I discovered that I forgot to include OneView.m in the make file (I know really silly) but thank you anyway.